# IO stream in socket Java

Tags: java, sockets, io, inputstream, outputstream

First I apologize for my English. I'm trying to make a Client-Server connection in Java but I have a problem getting response from the server. When I close the server first, the client will receive a response from the server. If I close the client first, nothing happens.

Here is the code of the server:

```
 BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(),"8859_1"),1024);
            DataOutputStream sendToClient= new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append(input.readLine());
            if(sb.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("lamoyenne")) {
                    System.out.println(Esclave.moyenneTarif());
                    sendToClient.writeBytes(String.valueOf(Esclave.moyenneTarif())); 
            }
            if(sb.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("nombrelieuentre100et200")) {
                    System.out.println(Esclave.nombreLieuEntre100et200());
                    sendToClient.writeBytes(String.valueOf(Esclave.nombreLieuEntre100et200())); 
            }
            else  {
                    System.out.println(Esclave.tarifParLieu(sb.toString()));
                    sendToClient.writeBytes(String.valueOf(Esclave.tarifParLieu(sb.toString())));
            }
```

Here is the code for the client:

```
System.out.println("Type in: ");
            this.connexion = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),44000);
            Writer output = new OutputStreamWriter(connexion.getOutputStream(), "8859_1");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            this.line = in.readLine();
            //DataOutputStream sendToServer  = new DataOutputStream(connexion.getOutputStream(),"8859_1");
            //sendToServer.writeBytes(this.line+'\n');

            output.write(this.line);
            output.flush();
            connexion.shutdownOutput();

            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connexion.getInputStream()));
            String temp = inFromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println("FROM SERVER: "+ temp);
```

Comment: You are writing to the client with a `DataOutputStream` and reading with a `Reader`. These are not compatible. The client is waiting for a *line* and a data stream doesn't have lines.

Comment: But when i close a connection, specially server first, a client will be recevied a response from server that show by System.out.println. And in some examples, it works. Here is an exemple (http://nguyenmanhit.blogspot.fr/2013/12/lap-trinh-socket-trong-java.html)

Comment: When the stream is closed, `readLine` will receive whatever you sent, and because you sent the bytes of strings, depending on encoding, it may work. But this is the wrong way to work. If you want to `readLine()`, be sure that you only send character data **and** send newlines on the other side, which `DataOutputStream` is the wrong tool for.

Comment: Thank you, so can you give me an example, key word or a tutorial that is the best way for request-response client-server socket in Java :)